# Remove items from array when removing from table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that builds up a table of dates as the user clicks on different dates in a date picker.
An array is also built up of the dates as they are added to the table
I also have a function to remove the dates from the table and array as they are clicked in the table

This all works except the last part. The dates are removed from the table but not the array and this is what I need help with.
I don't think it is appending

```
    //function to build up custom dates list
    var customStartDates = [];
    var customEndDates = [];

    $("#btnStartDate").on('click', function () {
        //I think this.value below is undefined..
        $('#customDatesTable').append("<tr id='" + this.value + "'><td>" +
            $("#StartDateCustom").val() + "<input type='hidden' 
               name='CustomStartDates[]' value='"
            + $("#StartDateCustom").val() + "'>" + "<input type='hidden' 
               name='CustomEndDates[]' value='"
            + $("#EndDateCustom").val() + "'>" + "</td>" + "<td>"
            + $("#EndDateCustom").val() + "</td>" + "<td 
            width='10%'>X</td>  </tr>");
        customStartDates.push( $("#StartDateCustom").val());
        customEndDates.push($("#EndDateCustom").val());
    });

    //function to remove custom dates from table
    $("#customDatesTable").on('click', 'td', function () {
        var item = $(this).parent().attr('value');
        $(this).parent().remove();

        customStartDates = $.grep(customStartDates, function (value) {
            return value != item;
        });
        customEndDates = $.grep(customEndDates, function (value) {
            return value != item;
        });
    });
```

Comment: As a general rule, it's much easier to build the arrays from the HTML when they are actually needed. Otherwise you end up with ugliness where you need to maintain the list as the user is still adding/removing items from it

Comment: When in doubt, log. I'd put `console.log(item + "/" + value);` into those greps and make sure these variables contain what I expect. I'm thinking, `item` probably doesn't.

Comment: Try to see it in `console.log(customStartDates);` that what is actually happening on each click?

Answer (score 1):

You should read `id` attribute of `<TR>`, as `<TD>` parent's can only be `<TR>` which doesn't have `value` attribute.

```
var item = $(this).parent().attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Send Start Date or End Date as Input parameter For a Function and Splice that Selected Date Index From the array.
Try this for both Start and End Dates

```
    function DeleteStartDate(StartDate) {
    for (var i = 0; i < customStartDates.length; i++) {
        if (StartDate == customStartDates[i]) {
            customStartDates.splice(i, 1);
            $("#btnStartDate").click();
        }
    }
   }
```